# CLR out of memory exceptions

Tags: c#, iis, memory-leaks

We are getting a lot of out of memory exceptions and we can't seem to diagnose what is happening. It seems to be an issue that happens that will spike memory usage from 300 MB to over 1 GB in a matter of a few minutes. Now this is an [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) application and has three [application domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_domain) running in separate thread pools.

We want to record when the *memory* exceptions are about to happen. So we can attempt to find a pattern. What is the best way to do this?

Is there a way to *query* the *memory* usage once a minute to see how high it is and send an alert email. Or maybe write an application that will monitor the CLR's memory usage? An ideas or a direction are more than welcome.

I am using [Performance Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_Monitor), but unless I am watching the process it is not that useful. I can only see what is was and when. I have also used the Red Gate Memory Profile tool, which is awesome by the way - only I cannot seem to hit upon the page or process that is causing the exception.

Comment: would be interested to know what you found to be the culprit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install ADPlus on your server (it's part of the [Windows Debugging Tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20110217084226/http://www.microsoft.com:80/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx)). When you start observing unusually high memory usage capture a memory dump using:

```
adplus -hang -p <PID> -quiet -o <dump file folder path>
```

`<PID>` is the process ID of the worker process which you can get from `tasklist.exe`.

If you're not always around when this issue occurs then you could automate capturing a memory dump using [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3):

1. Use DebugDiag in leak tracking mode to trigger a process dump when either your Private or Virtual memory use reaches a certain threshold. That said, I've not always found this reliable.
2. Use DebugDiag in Crash Mode to capture a dump whenever CLR exceptions are thrown. You can used the Advanced Settings to configure DebugDiag to produce a full memory dump upon encountering a CLR exception of type `System.OutOfMemoryException`. This is more reliable and will definitely trigger. Only use Advanced Settings -> Exceptions, don't touch the Unconfigured First Chance Exceptions, leave this setting at None.

Once you have your memory dump, fire up WinDBG then load the dump file and load up SOS and start poking about.

Tess Ferrandez's [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20120314124205/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/) is a great .NET debugging resource and she has plenty of articles and labs about how to track down memory leaks (these are archive.org links due to broken links):

> [If it is broken, fix it you should - memory issue articles](https://web.archive.org/web/20120323022809/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/tags/memory+issues/)
>
> [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 6:_Memory Leak](https://web.archive.org/web/20120511182250/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/03/17/net-debugging-demos-lab-6-memory-leak.aspx)
> [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 6:_Memory Leak - Review](https://web.archive.org/web/20120830180042/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/03/17/net-debugging-demos-lab-6-memory-leak-review.aspx)
> [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 7: Memory Leak](https://web.archive.org/web/20120304170614/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/03/25/net-debugging-demos-lab-7-memory-leak.aspx)
> [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 7: Memory Leak - Review](https://web.archive.org/web/20120418043130/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/04/03/net-debugging-demos-lab-7-memory-leak-review.aspx)

PerfMon counters are useful and can be used to confirm that you have a memory leak, but they don't tell the whole story. WinDBG and SOS are the tools you need to use to find out where your memory is being used.

Answer (score 2):

[Performance Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_Monitor), aka *Perfmon*, is your friend - it is **free** and **not intrusive** and **lightweight** and can be safely run on production servers if you use less frequent sampling (every few seconds). The minimum it can do is to sample memory and CPU usage for your processes (w3wp.exe) and store them on a file.

Since you have not shared what you are doing in the application I can't suggest performance counters to store, but there are plenty in the ASP.NET and .NET and CLR.

Since you are getting a CLR out of memory exception, my hunch is [GC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) is not working due to a pinned object or something. I doubt it is an unmanaged resource, such as bitmap, not being released although it could be.

Here are a list of counters I suggest:

**.NET CLR Memory**

- GC Handles
- Pinned Objects

**Process** for the w3wp.exe running your application

- A couple, but mostly *Working Set*

**ASP.NET**

- Managed Memory used

Comment: I dont think it is a pinned object we only 2 areas in code where we pin objects and they both seem fine, but it is a great point!

Comment: Would be easy to see if your Pinned objects counter goes up. I definitely recommend using perfmon as a startup.

Answer (score 1):

Try [RedGate Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm). I suppose it works with ASP.NET sites (their performance profiler definitely does).

Comment: I have it is a great tool but useless if you cannot reproduce the problem, since I dont know what series of events is causing the spike it is of no help. It is a great tool non the less tho.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *memory profiler*. There are a couple of good ones out there, e.g. JetBrains [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/) from Red Gate. There were a couple of discussions here at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=memory+profiler) with lots of other tips and recommendations.

Comment: Memory profiling is only useful if you know what generally what to do to find memory spike.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot afford a good profiler, you should use what Microsoft recommends in *[Production Debugging for .NET Framework Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ee817663(v=pandp.10))*.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [ADPlus](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350) in "crash" mode to capture a memory dump when the exception occurs, and then [WinDbg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) and [SOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg#SOS.dll) to figure out what's taking up all of the memory.

Comment: Crash mode won't dump the process because OOM exceptions often don't cause the worker process to crash.

Comment: Should use "hang" mode to capture process dumps when the exception occurs. Then dump analysis can show what is on the heap.

Comment: Actually, my mistake, but you need to configure ADPlus with a config script first. I find DebugDiag more handy for 95% of cases I've encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Use dotTrace or YourToolkit .NET where you can attach the profiler to the ASP process.

They have a trial version, so you don't need to spend money right away. Using these profilers you can select the timeline where memory starts increasing (you can see the memory usage visually in a graph), so it should be quite easy to select the range and understand what is causing the memory usage to shoot up so high.

Comment: ***"YourToolkit"*** is a fairly generic name. Can you add a reference to that tool? E.g., is it [this one](https://github.com/RicoSuter/MyToolkit)? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4165172/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if was written today).