# ASP.NET Memory Usage in IIS is FAR greater than in DevEnv. Is this normal?

Tags: asp.net, memory-management, iis-7.5

Greetings!

I have an ASP.NET app that scrapes data from a handful of external pages, parses the relevant bits and displays them in a table. Total data retrieved is 3-4MB and the resulting page is about 1MB. I am using synchronous WebRequest GetResponse for the retrieval, but the same problem existed using an asynchronous BeginGetResponse/EndGetResponse process.
There is no database access, no session storage, no caching, but an in-memory list of about 100 objects (total 1MB of data), plus a good amount of AJAX (AjaxControlToolkit). This issue appears on the very first run of the app, even if I have restarted IIS.

The issue:

When I run the app on my dev computer, the maximum commit charge is about 1.5GB. The biggest user, measured by Task Manager's VM Size, is WebDev.WebServer.exe (600MB). The app runs perfectly.

When I run it on my rent-a-server (IIS 7.5, 1GB RAM), the maximum commit charge is over 3.8GB. The biggest user is w3wp.exe at 2.7GB. IIS grinds to a halt and spits out a timed-out error page. 
Given my limited server budget and the hope of having multiple simultaneous users, I'm kind of in a panic.

Is this normal? If I bump the server RAM up to 4GB, will that be enough?
Will multiple users require even more memory?
Could the culprit be AJAX or the list of objects?

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some hard work, I have identified the culprit: our old nemesis the Endless Loop. Of course, if the development environment had thrown an exception, I would have caught and excised the problem - but it didn't.

I would say the lesson learned here is to understand that different versions of IIS and DevEnv respond to errors differently and that we must test the app in the same configuration in which it will be deployed.

Thanks everyone for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running this in your dev environment under IIS 7.5?
Make sure debug="false", not "true" in your web.config

Comment: VERY INTERESTING... I set up IIS 5.1 (the version that comes with XP) and ran the app across my network. The max commit charge on the 5.1 server was 1.3GB - even less than with the WebDev.WebServer. On subsequent runs, the memory usage actually decreased. Is IIS 7.5 that much of a memory hog?

Comment: You need to have a staging environment identical to your deployment environment.  Testing on XP (IIS 5) is absolutely nothing like testing on IIS 7 or IIS 6.

Comment: That makes sense. Since my site is not yet live, I am using the real server as the staging environment. Would it make a difference if I were to set up an identical environment here at my dev site? I would think that it would have the same results...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to dig out some debugging tools and capture a worker process dump of your production server, you won't be able to properly diagnose this issue with just PerfMon and Task Manager.

I posted this answer on Stack Overflow a while back which should get you started:

> [CLR out Of Memory Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164697/clr-out-of-memory-exceptions/4170476#4170476)